# How to validate all fields in one Vue-component with another components together (using Vee-Validate)?

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I use Vue.js `2.5.13` + Vee-Validate `2.0.3`. My code structure is:

**./component-one.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <input type="text" name="input_one" id="input_one"
           v-model="input_one" 
           v-validate="'required'"
           :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('input_one')}" />

    <component-two></component-two>

    <button @click="submitForm">Submit!</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
  import ComponentTwo from './component-two.vue'

  Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
    events: 'input|blur'
  })

  export default {
    name: "component-one",
    components: {
      ComponentTwo
    },
    data() {
      return {
        input_one: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitForm: function () {
        // Validate before submit form
        this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
          if (result) {
            alert('From Submitted!')
            return
          }
          alert('Correct them errors!')
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**./component-two.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <input type="text" name="input_two" id="input_two"
           v-model="input_two" 
           v-validate="'required'"
           :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('input_two')}" />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "component-two",
    data() {
      return {
        input_two: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How to validate field from `ComponentTwo`, when I click to `button @click="submitForm"` in `ComponentOne` (for save all form data at this component).

I have huge form, who made by similar small Vue-components (all collected in `ComponentOne`), would be great to validate all of them in one place.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger validateAll() on the component manually trough vue reference, like:

**parent component**

```
<template>
  <div>

    <input type="text" name="input_one" id="input_one"
           v-model="input_one" 
           v-validate="'required'"
           :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('input_one')}" />

    <component-two ref="validateMe"></component-two>

    <button @click="submitForm">Submit!</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
  import ComponentTwo from './component-two.vue'

  Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
    events: 'input|blur'
  })

  export default {
    name: "component-one",
    components: {
      ComponentTwo
    },
    data() {
      return {
        input_one: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitForm: async function () {
        // Validate before submit form
        const result = await this.$validator.validateAll() && await this.$refs.validateMe.$validator.validateAll()
        if (result) {
          alert('From Submitted!')
          return
        }
        alert('Correct them errors!')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: We should mark this answer as the correct one. Without using vee validate you can do this with "this.$refs["form"].validate() in your parent component for any form in a child component. Saved me here thanks man!

Comment: @KrisTryber How to do the validation with dynamic form with child components?